# Setting body value doesn't work on MAC Outlook 2016

Tags: outlook-web-addins

I'm using the 1.3 requirement set for setting/getting the body value of an appointment/meeting: `Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync(...)` and `Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setAsync(...)`

This works just fine literally everywhere and for all account types(Exchange on-premise and Outlook/Office365 accounts) except Outlook 2016 for MAC, where it fails to apply the html/text value of the body.

Checking the requirement sets (https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/tutorial-api-requirement-sets) MAC Outlook is listed as supporting all the requirement set versions(1.1 to 1.5) so it should support also the getAsync and setAsync methods for body property.

Any idea why it does not work?

UPDATE:

For setting value:

```
  function applyBody() {
    const $dBod = $.Deferred();
    try {
      Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setAsync(_appointmentInfo.body.value, { coercionType: _appointmentInfo.body.type }, function (asyncResult) {
        if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
          $dBod.resolve();
        }
        else {
          $dBod.reject(translate.getTranslation('ERROR_SETTING_BODY'));
        }
      });
    }
    catch (e) {
      $dBod.reject(e);
    }
    return $dBod.promise();
  }
```

For getting value:

```
  function getBody() {
    const $dBod = $.Deferred();
    getBodyType()
      .done(function (bodyType) {
        try {
          Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync(bodyType, function (asyncResult) {
            if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
              $dBod.resolve({ value: asyncResult.value, type: bodyType });
            }
            else {
              $dBod.reject(translate.getTranslation('ERROR_GETTING_BODY_VALUE'));
            }
          });
        }
        catch (e) {
          $dBod.reject(e);
        }
      })
      .fail($dBod.reject);

    return $dBod.promise();
  }
```

For getting body type:

```
  function getBodyType() {
    const $dBod = $.Deferred();
    try {
      Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getTypeAsync(function (asyncResult) {
        if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
          $dBod.resolve(asyncResult.value);
        }
        else {
          $dBod.reject(translate.getTranslation('ERROR_GETTING_BODY_TYPE'));
        }
      });
    }
    catch (e) {
      $dBod.reject(e);
    }
    return $dBod.promise();
  }
```

UPDATE2:

Method I use for concatenating initial body value with my html:

```
const filterNullsAndUndefined = function (array, char) {
    return array.filter(function (val) { return val; }).join(char);
  };
```

I call it like this  `filterNullsAndUndefined([intialBodyValue, myHtml],'');`

Where in my case the initialBodyValue is the value I get using `body.getAsync(...)` before appending myHtml to it( in order to preserve any text the user inserted before myHtml template gets appended).
If I set myHtml directly on the body (overwrite) it works.

UPDATE 3:

Below the result we got when we appended the word 'Christmass':

[appointment body as text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98I61.png)

Comment: Which build version are you using?

Comment: Version 15.41 (build 171205). Checking for update says no new update.

Comment: Could you post a code snippet of how you're using them? The APIs seem to work fine on our build.

Comment: updated the post with code snippets.

Comment: update: did a very simple test: injected html : '<b>this is a bold test</b>' using the above and it does work. So it must be the much more complex html which I try to inject which does not work. However, in the case when it fails to inject the async result still says 'Succeded' which is very confusing. Is there a way I send you the exact html in private to help pinpoint the problem as it contains confidential information? Thank you.

Comment: was able to pinpoint the exact problem: if I concatenate the initial item.body value with my html it does not work, if I overwrite the item.body with my html it works. Please see in my above UPDATE 2 how I concatenate the existing body value with my html. Any idea why concatenate does not work?

Comment: I must add that setting the above concatenation in the item's body fails even when the user did not type anything.

Comment: I have tested also by simply adding the 2 values : initialBodyValue + myHtml without using my routine above, same problem occurred. This is becoming a hot issue for us because we just got our application rejected again from Office Store because of this issue and we're not so sure that the problem is on our end.

Comment: it also happens on Outlook 2013 for Windows - exactly the same problem.

Comment: Is it possible to post the exact HTML by changing strings / function names that are confidential? Is the concatenation issue happening only for your HTML?

Comment: it happens with any text. I also tried with concatenating existing body value with '<b>this is a bold text</b>' and also with some value without HTML tags. Also, it happens regardless of whether user added text or not beforehand.

Comment: Ok so we tried adding the content always as coercion type text, see in UPDATE 3 the result. We appended the word 'Christmas' to the existing appointment body value and we set it back as text. This kind of explains it, when we concatenate the value it gets added after the end </html> tag of the body HTML.

Comment: what fixed it was getting the existing appointment body as text coercion type regardless of the actual coercion type of the appointment body:

...body.getAsync('text',...);

Comment: We are able to reproduce this issue now. Adding a <b>Text</b> after the </html> works on Outlook 2016 desktop, but not on the Mac. We will be fixing this soon.

Answer (score 0):

We are able to reproduce the issue. Adding a `<b>Text</b>` after the `</html>` works on Outlook 2016 desktop, but not on the Mac. We will be fixing this soon.

Comment: what will the fix be? We also reproduced this same issue on Outlook 2013 for Windows. Thank you.